# RTP MIDI between MAC and Windows

Tags: midi

I have Logic Pro running on MAC, and I have huge memory on my Windows desktop to run Kontakt as sampler, does RTP MIDI is the best way to connect between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll want to find something that allows you to run MTC over IP. I am fairly sure there is a feature built into OSX that allows you to route MTC over IP but as for receiving it on a windows platform - that I am not sure of. Certainly look for MTC over IP tools and software - that's where your answer lies.

Update: Checked out RTPMidi - looks like that might be a very good place to start.